# 連続して重複しているデータの削除の仕方がわかりません

Tags: r

連続して重複しているデータのみ削除の仕方がわかりません。
`distinct(X,Y,.keep_all = T)`で重複しているデータを削除する仕方はわかったのですが、連続関係なく同じ行が削除されてしまいます。
連続して同じデータのみ先頭の行を残して削除するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。何か方法ありませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html)パッケージ(`rleid()`関数)を使う方法を挙げておきます。

```
> library(data.table)
> df <- data.frame(
    X = c(1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5),
    Y = c(2, 2, 4, 6, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6),
    Z = c(letters[1:10])
  )

   X Y Z
1  1 2 a
2  1 2 b
3  3 4 c
4  5 6 d
5  1 2 e
6  2 3 f
7  2 3 g
8  2 3 h
9  3 4 i
10 5 6 j
```

カラム X, Y の値が同一の連続行を一行に約めます。

```
> aggregate(
    df,
    by  = list(rleid(df$X, df$Y)),
    FUN = function(x) x[1]
  )[, c(names(df))]

  X Y Z
1 1 2 a
2 3 4 c
3 5 6 d
4 1 2 e
5 2 3 f
6 3 4 i
7 5 6 j
```

ちなみに、上記の場合は重複行の先頭を取り出しますが、末尾の場合は `x[length(x)]` を使います。

```
> aggregate(
    df,
    by  = list(rleid(df$X, df$Y)),
    FUN = function(x) x[length(x)]
  )[, c(names(df))]

  X Y Z
1 1 2 b
2 3 4 c
3 5 6 d
4 1 2 e
5 2 3 h
6 3 4 i
7 5 6 j
```

なお、data.table だけで処理する場合は以下の様になります。

```
> data.table(df)[
    , k := rleid(X, Y)
  ][
    , N := .N, keyby = k
  ][
    ## 末尾行の場合は `mult = "last"`
    J(unique(k)), mult = "first"
  ][
    , names(df), with = FALSE
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`lag`を使うことで一つ前の値を取ることができます。
これを`filter`と組み合わせることで、一つ前の行のデータと異なる場合を抽出可能です。

```
# デモデータ作成
demo <- tibble(value=sample(LETTERS, 50, replace = TRUE))

# lagを使ってfilter
filtered <- demo %>% filter(value != lag(value, 1))
```